# Importing database from mysql dump file

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to import a mysql database from [here](https://www.azsecure-data.org/hacker-assets-portal.html) in Windows 10 workbench. I am trying to to that from the UI of Workbench. Navigating to server>data import i open the corresponding window and select the file i want to import( in my case attachments.sql). When i press data import i get:

```
 Restoring C:\Users\..\attachments.sql
Running: mysql.exe --defaults-file="C:\Users...\tmpi16ntmjj.cnf"  --protocol=tcp --host=localhost --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments  < "C:\\Users\\...ς\\attachments.sql"
ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 22: No database selected

Operation failed with exitcode 1
14:28:12 Import of C:\Users\Kospsych..\attachmments.sql has finished with 1 errors
```

which i don not understand. How could this be done properly?

Comment: "No database selected" sounds like the dump is missing the `USE` statement to select a database. What have you tried to resolve the problem? How is it related to programming?